# Get Random Friend FBML

Tags: fbml

Hey, say you have an array of friends that you've retrieved, how can you pick 1 random friend.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$array = array_slice(array_shuffle($array_orig), 0, 1);
```

This will get you one friend at random.